# How Java Runtime Maps to Targets

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jar, runtime

According to the Javadocs for Runtime [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html):

> Every Java **application** has a single instance of class Runtime that allows the **application** to interface with the environment in which the **application** is running. The current runtime can be obtained from the getRuntime method. An **application** cannot create its own instance of this class.

My question is: *what's their definition of an application*?

Is each JAR/WAR/EAR considered a standalone application? What about a plain ole' `Driver.class` class with a `main()` method? What about Java EE containers that house EARs and EJBs?

I guess I'm trying to understand how many `Runtime` instances could be up and running inside a complex (Java EE) system. And understanding that requires me to understand what specific "things" constitute an "application" in Java terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, one instance of the `Runtime` class per Java Virtual Machine execution.

How: The `Runtime` class makes use of the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern to control the number of instances during the running of the JVM. Note the class has no publicly available constructor so the only way to obtain an instance is by using the static `Runtime.getRuntime()` method. This method will always return the same instance.

Why: This class models the *runtime* of the JVM so it is an accurate representation to limit the number of instances to one per JVM execution.

Comment: Awesome! That brings everything into perfect focus. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Application is the bunch of classes that has entry point `main` that was executed by command `java -cp THECLASSPATH Main`.

Simple HelloWorld is a application as well as whole Java EE application server together with all components, plugins, adapters, Java EE applications deployed on it etc is application too.

Comment: Thanks @AlexR.  So if my JEE app (say, an EAR), used the log4j JAR, would the two share the same Runtime? If so, how/why?